# retrieve html from web page with chrome dev tools

Tags: python, html, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I need to retrive html using chrome dev tools protocol but I have sum problem and the behaviour is not how expected

I'm using https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/#method-getOuterHTML and PyChromeDevTools for manage chrome page

**from terminal**

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

**python script**

```
import PyChromeDevTools

chrome = PyChromeDevTools.ChromeInterface(host='localhost',port=9222)
chrome.Network.enable()
chrome.Page.enable()
chrome.Page.navigate(url="https://stackoverflow.com")
html_code=chrome.DOM.getOuterHTML()
print(html_code)
```

I'm not sure that DOM.getOuterHTML its the correct command but seems good for the purpose

Comment: add `DOM.getDocument()`

Comment: and you should use `chrome.wait_event("Page.loadEventFired", timeout=60)`

Comment: @Juraj thanks, resolved! so its possible instead execute some javascript code ? I'm ltryng  this method; https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime/#method-runScript

Comment: yes, most interaction with the page can be done by executing javascript. I had to learn the DOM interface to put files into a file-input. I use the protocol with a Java library and it may work differently than the python library. did you try it without DOM.getDocument(). Wasn't waiting for the page to load enough?

Comment: yes I forgot to set wait event timeout, so for html charging the page with the command DOM.getDocument() previusly it work. do you have en example in java for execute js ?

Comment: https://github.com/kklisura/chrome-devtools-java-client/tree/master/cdt-examples/src/main/java/com/github/kklisura/cdt/examples

Comment: @Juraj I have found a solution but now I have another trouble :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70730569/executing-javascript-code-thought-chrome-dev-tools-protocol

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the page is loaded in browser. The library you use has an example for that in README.

```
chrome.Page.navigate(url="http://www.google.com/")
chrome.wait_event("Page.loadEventFired", timeout=60)
```

The DOM interface may need `chrome.DOM.getDocument()` before accessing the elements.