# executing javascript code thought chrome dev tools protocol

Tags: javascript, python, request, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to execute some javascript code through CDTP and PyChromeDevTools library.
The following code works:

***from terminal:***

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

---

```
import PyChromeDevTools
chrome.Network.enable()
chrome.Page.enable()

script="t='hi,';c='this code works on the same line';console.log(t,c)"
chrome.Runtime.evaluate(expression=script)
```

I have some trouble when I need to inject complex js code not on the same line, for example function with javascript requests ecc..

```
script="t='hi,';
c='this code works not on the same line don't work ';
console.log(t,c)"
chrome.Runtime.evaluate(expression=script)
```

is it possible equal javascript file to runtime evaluate ? like this:

```
chrome.Runtime.evaluate(expression=file.js)
```

documentation of CDTP

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660435/pythonic-way-to-create-a-long-multi-line-string

Answer (score 1):

You should just load a js code from a file into str variable

```
def load_text(filename, mode='r', encoding='utf-8'):
    with open(filename, mode, encoding=encoding) as f:
        txt = f.read()
return txt

file_js = load_text('file.js')
chrome.Runtime.evaluate(expression=file_js)
```